# Travis conditional on branch after_success

Tags: travis-ci

In my travis script I have the following:

```
after_success:
- ember build --environment=production
- ember build --environment=staging --output-path=dist-staging
```

After both of these build, I conditionally deploy to S3 the one that is appropriate, based on the current git branch.

It works, but it would save time if I only built the one I actually need. What is the easiest way to build based on the branch?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use the `test` command as used [here](https://github.com/urbanmassage/hata/blob/master/.travis.yml).

```
after_success:
  - test $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "master" &&
    ember build
```

All travis env variables are available [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/).

Comment: Thanks! I thought it must be possible without a separate bash script.

Comment: yeah I was having the same issue yesterday. forgot where I read about using that `test` command but a simple `if` didn't work for me.

Comment: When Travis builds a PR targeted at master, $TRAVIS_BRANCH will be set to "master". So to make sure this is really only executed for master, you need to use `test $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "master" && test $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST = "false" && ember build`

Answer (score 8):

You can execute shell script in `after_success` and check the current branch using travis environment variables:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "master" ]]; then
  echo "We're not on the master branch."
  # analyze current branch and react accordingly
  exit 0
fi
```

Put the script somewhere in the project and use it like:

```
after_success:
- ./scripts/deploy_to_s3.sh
```

There might be other useful travis variables to you, they are listed [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/).

Comment: Also, don't forget to `chmod +x deploy_to_s3.sh` before pushing it, otherwise it will be not executable.

Comment: And, btw,  `[[ ... ]]`` seems to be not supported in `sh`, so I use `bash` there instead.

Answer (score 1):

With the following entry the script will only be executed if it is not a PR and the branch is master.

```
after_success:
  - 'if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "false" -a "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then bash doit.sh; fi'
```

It is not enough to evaluate `TRAVIS_BRANCH`. `TRAVIS_BRANCH` is set to master when a PR against master is created by a fork.

See also the description of `TRAVIS_BRANCH` on https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/:

- for push builds, or builds not triggered by a pull request, this is the name of the branch
- for builds triggered by a pull request this is the name of the branch targeted by the pull request
- for builds triggered by a tag, this is the same as the name of the tag (`TRAVIS_TAG`)

If you work with tags you have to consider `TRAVIS_TAG` as well. If `TRAVIS_TAG` is set, `TRAVIS_BRANCH` is set to the value of `TRAVIS_TAG`.

```
after_success:
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "false" -a \( "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" -o -n "$TRAVIS_TAG" \) ]; then doit.sh; fi
```

Answer (score -2):

I would say the above solutions are good because they would transfer to non-travis-ci build systems as well, but there is a feature in TravisCI for similar to this:

```
stages:
  - name: deploy
    # require the branch name to be master (note for PRs this is the base branch name)
    if: branch = master
```

Although I could not get it to work with `after_success`, the following page has a section on "Testing Conditions" which I didn't bother setting that up.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/

Comment: note that `after_success` is a build step within a job, whereas a travis stage is a different concept, it's a way to group jobs.  So the docs about conditional build stages are not about job steps.